# Resample time series data based on a column maximum value?

Tags: pandas, python-3.8, resampling

I have the below dataframe

```
Date              A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load  S_Gen
2010-01-01 00:00     30      20     40      40     70
2010-01-01 01:00     45      25     35      30     70
2010-01-01 02:00     25      22     30      25     55
```

What I want is to 'Daily Resample' based on maximum 'S_Gen' and if there are 'repeated' values then based on 'B-Gen'
Intended output:

```
Date       A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load  S_Gen
2010-01-01 45     25      35     30       70
```

Comment: Since the max S_Gen is 70 and there are 2 of them.  Shouldn't you take the row with the max B_Gen among those 2?  And isn't that the row with B_Gen == 40?

Comment: So sorry , Yes you are right  take the row with B_Gen == 40

Comment: Please, keep in mind , my dataframe is hourly dataframe and want to get row through everyday  in which S_Gen is maximum and if there are multiple repeated maximum values of  S_Gen then select based on maximum B_gen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8], [9, 10], [7, 10]]),
                   columns=['B_Gen', 'S_Gen',])
```

---

print the highest value in S_Gen:

```
df2.iloc[df2['S_Gen'].argmax()]
```

---

print the duplicates values:

```
duplicates = df2[df2.duplicated(subset=['S_Gen'], keep=False)]
```

---

Also can use - **groupby** and **max** - with printing only last row:

```
df2.sort_values('B_Gen').drop_duplicates('S_Gen', keep='last').tail(1)
```

Comment: Please, keep in mind , my dataframe is hourly dataframe and want to get row through everyday in which S_Gen is maximum and if there are multiple repeated maximum values of S_Gen then select based on maximum B_gen

Comment: Yes - try the last one - i tested on 2 test cases and it works - cause firstly sorting by B_Gen value - the hour index doesn't matter here I suppose

Comment: Thanks 'Piotr Zak ' I tested your code. It  provides maximum raw throughout the year but I want  maximum raw throughout  each day.

Comment: So, the result contains 365 rows in which the column S_Gen is maximum each day in over the Year under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date

df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'S_Gen', 'B_Gen'], ascending=[True, False, False])

df = df.drop_duplicates('Date')
```

```
# print(df)

         Date  A_Gen  A_Load  B_Gen  B_Load  S_Gen
1  2010-01-01     45      25     40      30     70
```

The first two lines convert `Date` column to datetime object and keeps only date part.

Then sort the dataframe by `Date`, `S_Gen`, `B_Gen` columns, where we want `Date` column is ascending, `S_Gen` column is descending and `B_Gen` column is descending.

At last we keep only first duplicates based on column `Date`.

Comment: Please, keep in mind , my dataframe is hourly dataframe and want to get row through everyday in which S_Gen is maximum and if there are multiple repeated maximum values of S_Gen then select based on maximum B_gen

Comment: @saadawad Notice that the `Date` column has been overwritten with `df['Date'].dt.date`  This made it daily and the `drop_duplicates` will work.

Comment: Thanks "piSquared" hit my point ,just I moved date column  to be index ,then everything OK

Comment: @saadawad I modify my answer to satisfy your need to keep the maximum `B_gen`. What do you mean by "moved date column to be index"? Is there anything I miss in your question?